# Find $k$ for real solutions of quadratic equation $\sin^4 x + 2(1 + k)\sin^2 x- k - 2 = 0$

Tags: quadratics

I'm stuck on this quadratic problem:
$$\sin^4 x + 2(1 + k)\sin^2 x- k - 2 = 0$$
$$k = ?$$
I substituted $t = \sin^2(x)$ this gave me $t^2 + 2(1 + k)t - k - 2 = 0$ and than I figured out that the discriminant is $k^2 + 3k + 3 \ge 0$ which is true for $k \in \mathbb{R}$. The other thing I figured out is that $t \in [0, 1]$ and this is where I don't know how to continue. The answer is supposed to be $k \in [-2, 1]$.

Edit: Forgot to mention that I'm interested in real number solutions only.

Comment: Do you need both the roots to be in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Tavish, Yeah because $\sin^2x\in[0,1]\:\forall\:x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Martund It could also be the case that one of the roots is in $[0,1]$, while the other is redundant.

Comment: Oh @Tavish, I didn't think of that.

Comment: The question is very unclear as written: $k$ could be anything.

Comment: @Tavish, look at my edited answer, $k$ cannot be anything lol.

Comment: @Martund It can be. Why do you assume this quadratic must have real solutions? Why do you assume $x\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Tavish, because the discriminant is non-negative.

Comment: @Martund That only means $\sin^2 x$ can be any of two real values, not necessarily in $[0,1]$ because $\sin x$ may be say, $2i$.

Comment: @Tavish, I strictly believe the OP is uninterested in complex values of sine function. It's a basic quadratic equations question. (Since the OP never used `analysis`, `complex numbers`, `real analysis`, or any such tag.)

Comment: @Martund That’s just a belief, you don’t know for sure. Although it is probable. My point is that more details should be added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express the equation as

$$k = \frac{2-2\sin^2 x - \sin^4 x }{2 \sin^2 x -1}
= \frac14 \left( \cos 2x - \frac3{\cos 2x}-6\right)
$$
For $x$ in the real domain, $k$ has the range $k\notin (-2,-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $0$ and $1$ enclose both the roots, and the given quadratic expression has positive leading coefficient, so the quadratic expression should take non-negative sign at both $0$ and $1$, or at least one of them should be the root. So if $f(t)$ denotes this quadratic expression, we have $f(0)\ge0$, and $f(1)\ge0$. Hence
$$(-k-2)\ge0\qquad\text{and}\qquad k+1\ge0$$
which is impossible, because $k+1\ge 0\implies k+2\ge 1\implies -k-2\le -1$. Hence no such $k$ exists.